# GAS: Send automatically emails from spreadsheet with date ant time info

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, spreadsheet

I've the following columns in a spreadsheet

| email | name | link | date | time | file | subject | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a.d@abc.com | Sam Z | abc | 18.01.23 | 14:41:00 | def | abc | Hello World |

With following code deployed as add-on in google apps script console I want to autamtically send emails to certain adresses at certain date and time, I#ve activeted a trigger to run the app every minute, but somehow it does not work...any hint what could be wrong? I'm 100% sure it is connected with the right spreadsheet

```
   function sendReminderEmails() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1h570Eb4IqAaAHciQzz0U9oY_uqGo9UDzpWtth78NkCY").getSheetByName("test");
      var data = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      // console.log(data);
      for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        var email = data[i][0];
        var name = data[i][1];
        var link = data[i][2];
        var date = data[i][3];
        var time = data[i][4];
        var file = data[i][5];
        
        var now = new Date();
        
        if (now.toLocaleDateString() == date && now.toLocaleTimeString() == time) {
          MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Reminder: " + file, "Hello " + name + ",\n\nThis is a reminder about the " + file + " at " + link + " on " + date + " at " + time + ".");
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems with your code and the way you're approaching this problem:

- The variables `date` and `time` that you got from the Sheet are `Date` objects, so you also have to call `toLocaleDateString()` and `toLocaleTimeString()` on them if you want to compare them with the `now` values.
- Even if you correct the above, the value returned by `toLocaleTimeString()` is a time in the format `HH:MM:SS XM` so the trigger would have to run at the *exact* same second as the time in your Sheet, which is very unlikely. You would need to cut out the seconds to compare the exact minute.
- Even if you correct the above and compare the exact minute, Apps Script's [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) are slightly randomized, so there's no guarantee either that the trigger will run every single minute, and there may be a gap of a few minutes between executions.

My suggestion is to instead try something like rounding down the times to the nearest 10-minute mark and set the trigger to run every minute to compare the times. You would also need an extra checkbox column to mark them as done and avoid sending multiple emails. It may look something like this example:

```
function sendReminderEmails() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1h570Eb4IqAaAHciQzz0U9oY_uqGo9UDzpWtth78NkCY").getSheetByName("test");
  var data = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var email = data[i][0];
    var name = data[i][1];
    var link = data[i][2];
    var date = data[i][3];
    var time = data[i][4];
    var file = data[i][5];
    var checked = data[i][7];

    var now = new Date();

    var roundedtime = time.getHours() + ":" + Math.floor(time.getMinutes() / 10) * 10
    var roundednow = now.getHours() + ":" + Math.floor(now.getMinutes() / 10) * 10

    if (now.toLocaleDateString() == date.toLocaleDateString() && roundednow == roundedtime && !checked) {

      MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Reminder: " + file, "Hello " + name + ",\n\nThis is a reminder about the " + file + " at " + link + " on " + date + " at " + time + ".");
      spreadsheet.getRange(i + 1, 8).setValue(true)
    }
  }
}
```

The sheet would look like this:
[image]

In this case `roundedtime` and `roundednow` would cut off the seconds and round down the minutes so, something like `14:41:00` would become `14:40`, so the email would be sent when the trigger fires at any time between 14:40 to 14:49, then the checkbox is selected with `spreadsheet.getRange(i + 1, 8).setValue(true)` so it won't send another email within the same timeframe. Most often the emails will be sent closer to the lower bound.

Another possibility could be to instead create the triggers [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically) by using the time in the Sheet. If you use a trigger to fire at a specific time it will run once and then expire, but there's a [limit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) of 20 triggers / user / script, so you wouldn't be able to use this method with a lot of data. Either way, keep in mind that you'll need to sacrifice some accuracy if you want your current approach to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed feedback, it helped me to get a better understanding of the "Date" object!